# Javascript: Date Issue

Tags: javascript, datetime

I create a new Date in javascript and provide it the string value of a date like so:

```
>>> string_date = '2009-09-09';
>>> var myDate = new Date(string_date);
>>> myDate
Tue Sep 08 2009 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EST) { locale="en"}
```

The string date comes from a calendar picker widget and I write the value from that widget to a hidden input field. The format of the date is YYYY-MM-DD. Also, with the code above, I write the date selected to a div to show the date in a nice way. However, the users are confused by the date shown that way. So, how can I show the date in such a way that the locale is not considered and so, write it as Sep 09, 2009?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Nobody's commented on the fact that your string starts off with Sep 09, but when you print it out you get Sep 08.

Comment: I know. But to I took the accepted answer's way of handling this. In stead of creating a date object, I parse the string from the date picker and then create a new string from it that can be displayed to the users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December");

var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

document.write(m_names[curr_month] + " " + curr_date + ", " + curr_year);

//-->
</script>
```

More here: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/javascript_date_and_time.php3

Comment: Thanks for this. I've modified a bit to fit my need. :)

Comment: No problem... it actually solves an issue for me at the same time.  Although none of the examples are exactly what I need, it
s enough to get us in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

`myDate.toDateString()`

If you don't want the day, `(1 + myDate.getMonth()) + ' ' +  myDate.getDate() + ', ' + myDate.getFullYear()`.

If you don't need that comma, you can write that as `[1 + myDate.getMonth(), myDate.getDate(), myDate.getFullYear()].join(' ')`

Edit: Forgot that getMonth() doesn't return human-readable names, and that you'd have to store them in an array as per @NinjaCat.

Comment: You'd almost certainly want to use `myDate.getMonth() + 1` because Javascript dates count months from zero, unlike the humans of the world.

Comment: @Pointy @mplungjan , yeah I remembered that shortly after posting and edited to reflect. I hate that getMonth() is 0 indexed and getDate() is not so, so much. You unfortunately have to use an external array to  represent human-readable month names.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = myDate.split(' ');
var strDate = parts[1] + ' ' + parts[2] + ', ' + part[3]
```

If you go the "correct" way and use `getXXX` remember that `getMonth()` needs +1 since JS months start at 0.